# PHP: Undefined index by retrieving $_POST data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

It's a very simple code, I was trying to do an `ajax submit` to work. Until here, ajax is working correct, but Why cannot print out $_POST data?

console.log

`<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: fieldText in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\rajax.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />`

sendajax.php

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="fieldText" value="">
      <button type="submit" id="save">Send</button>     
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //alert("Jquery's Working");
        $("#save").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //alert("Click Event is working");
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:'rajax.php',
                data: {field: $("input[name=fieldText]").val()},
                success: function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                    //alert($("input[name=fieldText]").val()); #Print Value is working
                },
                error: function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

recajax.php

```
<?php 

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
        $test = $_POST['fieldText'];
        echo $test;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your variable name isn't `fieldText`, it's `field`. try changing it in your PHP.

```
<?php 

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
       $test = $_POST['field'];
       echo $test;
    }

?>
```

Comment: hmm... I'm retired from php. It worked. Can you explain where I overlook? Because, the name that I got in input is `fieldText`

Comment: Yea but you passed it as `field` in your data attribute. the `$_POST` variable is an associative array (in your case), and it reflect the value of the `data` attribute of your AJAX call.

Comment: which is `data: {field: $("input[name=fieldText]").val()},`. not `data: {fieldText: $("input[name=fieldText]").val()},` Notice the key of your value has changed.

Comment: Oh man, you're right! I forgot completely about this. Thank you man

Comment: No problem, have a nice day !